# SQL Server 2012 - Select queries leap year

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, select

I have a little issue with one my queries. The entire query is actually is a little long since it includes a `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 'ITV' = CASE WHEN tblIntake.StaffID Is Null THEN '<Unknown>' ELSE
(tblStaffMember.StaffLast + ', ' + tblStaffMember.StaffFirst + CASE WHEN
tblStaffMember.StaffMI Is Null THEN '' ELSE ' ' + tblStaffMember.StaffMI END) END, 
tblMember.[LAST], tblMember.[FIRST], 
'DueDate' = DATEADD(m, 6,CAST(CONVERT(Varchar(10),
MONTH(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' + CONVERT(Varchar(10),
DAY(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' + CONVERT(Varchar(10),YEAR(GETDATE()))As
 DateTime)), 'Type' = '6 Month Appt' 

From tblIntake LEFT JOIN tblStaffMember ON tblIntake.StaffID =
tblStaffMember.StaffID LEFT JOIN tblMember ON 
tblIntake.KEY = tblMember.KEY 

Where tblIntake.UnEnrollDate Is Null AND
DATEADD(m,6,CAST(CONVERT(Varchar(10),MONTH(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' +
CONVERT(Varchar(10),DAY(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' +
CONVERT(Varchar(10),YEAR(GETDATE()))As DateTime)) > GETDATE() AND 
DATEADD(m, 6,CAST(CONVERT(Varchar(10),MONTH(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' +
CONVERT(Varchar(10),DAY(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' +
CONVERT(Varchar(10),YEAR(GETDATE()))As DateTime)) <= DATEADD(d, 45, GETDATE())
```

So, I have this wonderful query. Everything was running okay until a user entered a leap year date for `ENROLLDATE` in `tblIntake`. How would I go about fixing it? My other `UNION` does the same `SELECT` statements with the exception of for when it does

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GetDate()-1)) as DateTime > '4th line from the bottom
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GetDate()-1)) as DateTime > '2nd line from the bottom
```

EDIT:

Receiving this error when I run the query

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an  out-of-range value.

I tried running the separate queries, and it seems like I'm only getting the error when I do this..

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GetDate()-1)) as DateTime > '4th line from the bottom
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GetDate()-1)) as DateTime > '2nd line from the bottom
```

After UNION ALL

EDIT 2:

I've been working off Sean's answer which makes more sense. Here is the code that I've got....

```
SELECT 'CSC' = case when tblIntake.staffID is null Then '<notIndicated>' Else (tblStaffMember.staffLast + ',' + tblStaffMember.StaffFirst + case when tblStaffMember.staffMI is null then '' else ' ' + tblStaffMember.staffMI END)end  
, tblMember.[Last], tblMember.[First]
,'Due' = DateADD(m,6,cast(tblIntake.enrolldate as datetime))
,'Type' = '6 Month Review'
from tblMembEnrollment
left join tblStaffMember on tblIntake.staffID = tblStaffMember.staffID 
left join tblMember on tblIntake.SBkey=tblMember.sbkey
where tblIntake.unEnrollDate is null and dateAdd(m, 6, tblIntake.enrolldate)  > GETDATE()
and dateadd(m, 6, cast(tblIntake.enrolldate as DateTime))<= DateAdd(d,45,GetDate())
```

The issue I'm seeing is that in the old query, when the code takes apart the EnrollDate into days, months and years for years it used GET DATE, see below in between *** ****

```
Where tblIntake.UnEnrollDate Is Null AND
DATEADD(m,6,CAST(CONVERT(Varchar(10),MONTH(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' +
CONVERT(Varchar(10),DAY(tblIntake.EnrollDate)) + '/' +
CONVERT(Varchar(10),***YEAR(GETDATE()))As DateTime))*** > GETDATE()
```

Now it was easier done this way since he did take it apart, how is it that I can do it with my full Enroll date.

Comment: What is the error returned? What have you tried?

Comment: Go about fixing... *what*? What's wrong? Is it breaking with an error? If so, what's the message? Are you getting unexpected results? If so, please describe.

Comment: @BobKaufman see edit. I tested it without the 02/29/2016 and it works fine, if i test with it - get this error.

Comment: Yowza!!! What is that wall of text for a where clause supposed to be doing? If your tables are very large this is going to be horribly slow as this is nonSARGable due to columns being wrapped in functions. Surely there is a better way to achieve whatever this is trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange this is a finished legacy application built by an older programmer. This data is used for a report. I guess I'm just trying to find a way to fix this leap year issue.

Comment: I get that it is a legacy system but what is that where clause supposed to be doing? It is a train wreck of gibberish. What is the datatype for EnrollDate? It appears to most likely be a datetime column? Why all the crazy nonsense parsing it to string portions and slamming back together again? I realize you didn't write this but without an understanding it is hard to to know where to turn here.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a situation where sql server would handle it automatically if you just kept them as dates, but because you're splitting the date into component parts, then adding six months, then smashing it all together again...

Comment: All dates are 'datetime'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do here you can greatly simplify this. Please note that I used aliases everywhere instead of repeating the table name over and over. Also, I used the datepart names instead of the abbreviations as they are much more clear. Last but not least I just used the existing datetime value. I converted them to the date datatype as what it appears the existing logic is doing is converting it to a date value to avoid the time portion. This as fairly common prior to 2005 when the date datatype was added. I also reduced all the nested case expressions into something much easier to read.

```
SELECT 'ITV' = ISNULL(sm.StaffLast + ', ' + sm.StaffFirst + ISNULL(' ' + sm.StaffMI, ''), '<Unknown>')
    , tblMember.[LAST]
    , tblMember.[FIRST]
    , 'DueDate' = DATEADD(month, 6, convert(date, tblIntake.EnrollDate))
    , 'Type' = '6 Month Appt' 
From tblIntake i
LEFT JOIN tblStaffMember sm ON i.StaffID = sm.StaffID 
LEFT JOIN tblMember m ON i.KEY = m.KEY 
Where i.UnEnrollDate Is Null 
    AND DATEADD(month, 6, convert(date, i.EnrollDate)) > GETDATE() 
    AND DATEADD(month, 6, convert(date, i.EnrollDate)) <= DATEADD(day, 45, GETDATE())
```

--EDIT--

With the clarity of rules I think this should be what you are looking for. This has the advantage of also being SARGable so that any index on i.EnrollDate can be utilized.

```
Where i.UnEnrollDate Is Null 
    AND convert(date, i.EnrollDate) > DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
    AND convert(date, i.EnrollDate) <= DATEADD(day, -45, GETDATE())
```

Comment: this looks great but please see the edit. I guess I'm working on re-writing the query to make it simpler as it doesn't do anythign complicated. Like you said this query was used in older systems and was imported for this report. Please see edit.

Comment: Do you know what this is supposed to be doing or do you have to parse somebody else's mess into something usable? If you know the rules we can make this even simpler. Deciphering it is more challenging.

Comment: This is a working query. The Leap date is what's causing me to rewrite it. Basically what this is supposed to do is take all the names  and show NAMES (first,Last, MI) of people with '6 month appointment' due in the next 45 days.

Answer (score 2):

I'd replace all of those date parts and `convert`s with `dateadd`, something like:

```
declare @test datetime
set @test = '2-29-2016'

select cast(@test as varchar(11))
, cast(dateadd(mm, 6, @test) as varchar(11))
, cast(dateadd(yy, -1, @test) as varchar(11))
```

If you keep the dates as datetimes, SQL server will automatically correct for leap years, shorter months, etc.  The query above returns:

```
Feb 29 2016   Aug 29 2016   Feb 28 2015
```